# How do I remove the cotton from my Frigidaire oven?

Tags: kitchens, oven

[image: urine in oven]

How do I remove the cotton from my Frigidaire oven? It smells like rat urine.

Comment: Do you mean the insulation?  It's certainly not cotton...

Answer (score 1):

Oven door seals generally just pull off.

The replacement pushes back into the slot revealed.

Often the sealing strip has several metal spring clips that you push into holes provided for that purpose.

An example video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJfp2EgFF-M

Comment: I suspect the question is more about the sidewall insulation batting.